Mapbox queryRenderedFeatures() returns empty array
I am following this example here https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/ to retreive the infomation of point of the map. The only thing i change is that I wish to it retrieve when on click.
Here is my code.
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import MAP, { MapRef } from "react-map-gl";


const MAPBOX_TOKEN = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmlraWQiLCJhIjoiY2xuZmZtNXN0MDcwcDJybzJiNXM0cmU0aSJ9.umSCVKmjN4XB-srFrFOqFQ';

export default function MapboxMap(props: User): React.ReactElement {
  const mapRef = useRef<MapRef>(null);
  const [mapStyle, setMapStyle] = useState("mapbox://styles/mapbox/standard");

  const getMapPointInfo = (e: mapboxgl.MapMouseEvent) => {
    console.log("Info at this point", e.point);
    const features = mapRef.current?.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point);

    const displayProperties = ["type", "properties", "id", "layer", "source", "sourceLayer", "state"];

    const displayFeatures = features.map((feat) => {
      const displayFeat = {};
      displayProperties.forEach((prop) => {
        displayFeat[prop] = feat[prop];
      });
      return displayFeat;
    });

    console.log("Info at this point", features);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      <MAP
        initialViewState={viewport}
        mapboxAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        mapStyle={mapStyle}
        ref={mapRef}
        attributionControl={false}
        projection={{ name: "globe" }}
        onClick={(e) => {
          getMapPointInfo(e);
        }}
      >
        <GeocoderControl mapboxAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN} position="top-left" setInfo={setPanelInfo} />
      </MAP>
    </div>
  );
}

However, it only returns an empty array and I am not sure what I did wrong. Is it a bug on react? Any help is appreciated.

I found that maybe I need to specify the interactive layer ids from here OnClick for mapbox Layer but I couldn't find any options for this proper in the documentation.

the layer ID that the map features contains must be passed as an argument in queryRenderedFeatures. unfortunately it looks like in the standard style, the base map is wrapped and tucked away from the API. track this thread here:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/13160
